Children's sci-fi movie from mid-70s to early 80s about a child inventor
I remember a live-action sci-fi movie from my youth (mid-70s to early 80s) that was most likely made for children. It most likely was made in the US. In it, a boy invented all sorts of gadgets. I remember one scene where he had a gadget to open the gate door at a bank. He went on a number of adventures with his friend while causing havoc with the gadgets he created and getting in trouble with his parents.
I don't remember him causing any major damage with his gadgets until the very end of the movie. In the ending, I believe he enabled a gadget that turned the world upside down. I wish I remembered more details, and I'm sure I am describing some of this incorrectly.
Does anyone remember this? I do remember it was a fairly good movie, but I was just a kid, so who knows how good it really was.

This sounds a lot like a Disney Movie-of-the-week kinda thing. They had a lot of these short films in production; The Whiz Kid, Ask Max, etc

Was this live-action or animated? And when you say "turned the world upside down" - do you mean the entire globe, or that sky and earth transposed?

Was this from the USA/Canada? If not ... do you know where it may have been from?

I'm pretty sure it was a movie made in the USA. It was live-action. When I said "turned the world upside down", I kind of remember the final scene being just upside down.

Could it be Where's Willie? (1978)?
According to a review by temcgowan on IMDb:

He had invented some kind of remote control device that would do the impossible. An example was a scene where he was in school, he discretely points the remote at the clock on the wall and the time fast-forwards, causing the bell to ring and class lets out early. There were other scenes involving this same gadget where, if I recall, it confused traffic lights and caused a traffic jam. There is also something about a bank, where I believe the kid uses the remote to bypass the bank's security.


I think you may be correct! I'm going to order the DVD and find out. I'll report back. Thanks!

You're right, thanks, just watched it on Youtube (well, skimmed through it). That's definitely the movie. It's amazing how much the memory of something you saw as a kid can become distorted and warped. It's really a bad movie. I've been thinking all this time it was a lost gem from my childhood.
